# Camping Equipment for Kruger

Tags: camping, south-africa, kruger-national-park

I'll be spending a couple of weeks with my girlfriend in the Kruger National Park in South Africa from Friday, a combination of camping and the cheapest huts. We have most of the equipment we need but wondering if we should pick up:

1. Camping chairs
2. A braai (barbecue) grid

It looks like there will be concrete bases, but judging from other campsites I have been to here, there will be no chairs or bench and no metal grid to put on the braai (barbecue).

We'll be staying at Satara, Lataba, Oiliphants, Skakuzza and Mompani.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You definitely need both those items.

Not all the campsites have concrete bases. Most campsites are first come first serve when it comes to selecting you site.

You will also be thankful for taking your own barbecue grid. Sometimes, although not always, the barbecue grid, or even the barbecue itself is somewhat unusable or impractical (dirty, broken, uncomfortable location etc.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just back from Kruger. There were a good number of serviceable braais in the camp's, but as you say, sometimes they were all taken or damaged. Picked up a braai grid and chairs from Pick and Pay (Common local supermarket) easily and cheaply.